# Showing AdMob Interstitial ad even after closing the app

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, admob, interstitial

i am making android app with AdMob Integrated in my app , i am using AdMob to show ad after 20 seconds of WebView loaded. the problem is when user close the app before 20 seconds Interstitial ads still show, which is against the google AdMob policy, how can i make that when user exit the activity or app , Interstitial ad should not be display

this is my code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         interAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
         interAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
         AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                 .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                 .build();
         interAd.loadAd(adRequest);
         interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    interAd.show();
         }
     });

     interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
         @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
             Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
            }
        });
    }
} , 20000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass your handler when onDestroy called

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            interAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
            interAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                    .build();
            interAd.loadAd(adRequest);
            interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override

                public void onAdLoaded() {
                   if(interAd.isLoaded() && interAd !=null)
                      interAd.show();
                }
            });

            interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
            }
    });

        }
    } , 20000);



 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("MainActivty","onDestroy removing callbacks...");
        handler.removeCallbacks(myHandler);
        interAd =null
        super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: not works error : incompatible types. required android.os.handler found boolean and i have android.os.handler in import also

Answer (score 0):

Add  onBackpress  and onDestroy overides and remove your handlers callbacks and set the interstitialad variable to null in each of them.

```
@Override
protected void onBackpressed() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(your handler name here);
    interAd =null
    super.onBackpressed();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(your handler name here);
    interAd =null
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

If you want to also handle this if your app goes in background then add onPause overide too.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(your handler name here);
    interAd =null
    super.onPause();
 }
```

Hope that helps.

Let me know if you need further assistance.